# Showing $S\circ T=id_{\mathbb{V}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{W}$ be an injective linear transformation and $S:\mathbb{W}\rightarrow \mathbb{V}$ be a surjective linear transformation with $\mathbb{V}$ and $\mathbb{W}$ finite-dimensional vector spaces.

How can I show that $S\circ T=id_{\mathbb{V}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because it is not true in general. Even in dimension one. Even if the maps are bijective. For instance, $T,S:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R $ where $$ T (c)=2c,\ \ \ \ \ S (c)=3c. $$

Answer (score 0):

This need not be the case. Here is a counterexample:
Let $V=\Bbb{R}$ and $W=\Bbb{R}^2$. Define $T(r)=(r,0)$ and $S(r,s)=s$. Then, it should be clear that $T$ is injective and $S$ is surjective. But $S\circ T(r)=S(r,0)= 0$ for each $r \in \Bbb{R}$.